# How to POST an XML file using cURL on php?

Tags: php, xml, post, curl

I am using a local server on my computer and i am trying to make 2 php scripts to send an xml file and receive it.

To send the xml file i use this code :

```
<?php
  /*
   * XML Sender/Client.
   */
  // Get our XML. You can declare it here or even load a file.
  $file = 'http://localhost/iPM/books.xml';
  if(!$xml_builder = simplexml_load_file($file))
  exit('Failed to open '.$file);

  // We send XML via CURL using POST with a http header of text/xml.
  $ch = curl_init();
  // set URL and other appropriate options
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://localhost/iPM/receiver.php");
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: text/xml'));
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $xml_builder);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 0);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, 'http://localhost/iPM/receiver.php');
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
  $ch_result = curl_exec($ch);
  curl_close($ch);
  // Print CURL result.
  echo $ch_result;
?>
```

To receive the xml file i use this code :

```
<?php
  /*
   * XML Server.
   */
  // We use php://input to get the raw $_POST results.
  $xml_post = file_get_contents('php://input');
  // If we receive data, save it.
  if ($xml_post) {
    $xml_file = 'received_xml_' . date('Y_m_d-H-i-s') . '.xml';
    $fh       = fopen($xml_file, 'w') or die();
    fwrite($fh, $xml_post);
    fclose($fh);
    // Return, as we don't want to cause a loop by processing the code below.
    return;
  }
?>
```

When i run the post script i get this error :

```
Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\xampp\htdocs\iPM\main.php on line 17
```

which refers to line :

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $xml_builder);
```

which i dont know what exactly does. The xml file i receive is created but when i open it i get this :

```
XML Parsing Error: syntax error
Location: file:///C:/xampp/htdocs/iPM/received_xml_2013_01_14-01-06-09.xml
Line Number 1, Column 1:
```

I tried to comment this specific line as i thought the problem lies there but then when i run my post script i get this error :

```
Request entity too large!

The POST method does not allow the data transmitted, or the data volume exceeds the capacity limit.

If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster. 

Error 413
```

but the xml file is only 5kbs so this is not the problem.

Does anyone have any idea what i should do here? All i am trying to do is make a script to send an xml file and a script to receive it and save it as an xml.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $foo)` sets your request's body, the data to be posted. It expects `$foo` to be a set of key-value pairs provided either as an array:

```
$foo = array(
    'foo' => 'some value',
    'bar' => 2
);
```

or as a percent-encoded string:

```
$foo = 'foo=some%20value&bar=2'
```

Instead, you're providing `$xml_builder` variable which is a `SimpleXMLElement` object returned by `simplexml_load_file($file)`.

Try this:

```
$postfields = array(
    'xml' => $your_xml_as_string; // get it with file_get_contents() for example
);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postfields);
```

Then on the receiving end:

```
$received_xml = $_POST['xml'];
```

Comment: I am trying what you say but i get an error : Multiple annotations found at this line:
 - syntax error, unexpected 'EOF', 
  expecting ')'
 - syntax error, unexpected '=', 
  expecting ')'
 - 1 changed line   
 . Are you sure the synta is correct? also what do you mean to put that on the receiving end? Where exactly? In the end of the receiver.php file? I dont see that to have sense !?

Comment: I just fixed it like this : i used the file_get_contents like this :  $xml = file_get_contents("books.xml");   and then i just put :  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $xml);  and it worked!

Comment: Using the SimpleXMLElement you would need to do $xml_builder->asXml();