# How to send an XML-file with PHP cURL?

Tags: php, xml, curl

This question is market as answered in this thread:

[How to POST an XML file using cURL on php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14309796/how-to-post-an-xml-file-using-curl-on-php)

But that answer wasn't really the correct answer in my opinion since it just show how to send XML code with cURL. I need to send an XML **file**.

Basically, I need **this C# code** to be converted to PHP:

```
public Guid? UploadXmlFile()
{
    var fileUploadClient = new WebClient();
    fileUploadClient.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/xml");
    fileUploadClient.Headers.Add("Authorization", "api " + ApiKey);

    var rawResponse = fileUploadClient.UploadFile(Url, FilePath);
    var stringResponse = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(rawResponse);

    var jsonResponse = JObject.Parse(stringResponse);
    if (jsonResponse != null)
    {
        var importFileId = jsonResponse.GetValue("ImportId");
        if (importFileId != null)
        {
            return new Guid(importFileId.ToString());
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

I have tried in several ways and this is my latest try.

**The cURL call:**

```
/**
 * CDON API Call
 *
 */
function cdon_api($way, $method, $postfields=false, $contenttype=false)
{
    global $api_key;

    $contenttype = (!$contenttype) ? 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' : $contenttype;

    $curlOpts = array(
        CURLOPT_URL => 'https://admin.marketplace.cdon.com/api/'.$method,
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => TRUE,
        CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 60,
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array('Authorization: api '.$api_key, 'Content-type: '.$contenttype, 'Accept: application/xml')
    );

        if ($way == 'post')
        {
            $curlOpts[CURLOPT_POST] = TRUE;
        }
        elseif ($way == 'put')
        {
            $curlOpts[CURLOPT_PUT] = TRUE;
        }

        if ($postfields !== false)
        {
            $curlOpts[CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS] = $postfields;
        }

    # make the call
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt_array($ch, $curlOpts);
    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    return $response;
}
```

**The File Export:**

```
/**
 * Export products
 *
 */
function cdon_export()
{
    global $api_key;

    $upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();
    $filepath = $upload_dir['basedir'] . '/cdon-feed.xml';

    $response = cdon_api('post', 'importfile', array('uploaded_file' => '@/'.realpath($filepath).';type=text/xml'), 'multipart/form-data');

    echo '<br>Response 1: <pre>'.print_r(json_decode($response), true).'</pre><br>';

    $data = json_decode($response, true);

        if (!empty($data['ImportId']))
        {
            $response = cdon_api('put', 'importfile?importFileId='.$data['ImportId'], false, 'text/xml');

            echo 'Response 2: <pre>'.print_r(json_decode($response), true).'</pre><br>';

            $data = json_decode($response, true);
        }
}
```

But the output I get is this:

---

Response 1:

stdClass Object
(
    [Message] => The request does not contain a valid media type.
)

---

I have experimented around with different types at the different places, `application/xml`, `multipart/form-data` and `text/xml`, but nothing works.

How do I do to make it work? How do I manage to send the XML file with cURL?

Comment: From the PHP manual `"CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS: The full data to post in a HTTP "POST" operation. To post a file, prepend a filename with @ and use the full path."`

Comment: @RamRaider Yes, as you see that's exactly how I do. But it won't work.

Comment: @RamRaider the @ approach was deprecated years ago, became unreliable 5.5, and even more unreliable in 5.6, and completely stopped working in 7.0, use CURLFile instead of @

Comment: @hanshenrik - I was unaware of that, I still have php 5.3.2 so have never read about that in the manual :( time for an upgrade perhaps

Answer (score 1):

to me, it looks like the C# code just does the equivalent of

```
function UploadXmlFile(): ?string {
    $ch = curl_init ( $url );
    curl_setopt_array ( $ch, array (
            CURLOPT_POST => 1,
            CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array (
                    "Content-Type: application/xml",
                    "Authorization: api " . $ApiKey 
            ),
            CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => file_get_contents ( $filepath ),
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true 
    ) );
    $jsonResponse = json_decode ( ($response = curl_exec ( $ch )) );
    curl_close ( $ch );
    return $jsonResponse->importId ?? NULL;
}
```

but at least 1 difference, your PHP code adds the header `'Accept: application/xml'`, your C# code does not

Comment: Hmm, the `$response` is empty now. It should contain json datas.

Comment: I agree. The trick is to set CURLOPT_POSTFIELD to a **string** so that cURL does not attempt to look into Content-Type as it otherwise would (and allows you to use the correct `application/xml` Content-Type). I've had to do the same for a SOAP client some time ago and this was a major stumbling block.

Comment: I added it as string and now I get `The request does not contain a valid multipart content.` whatever I do...

Comment: @PeterWesterlund then that's a bug with the api server, let the api devs know that when you send the header `Content-Type: application/xml`, the server try to parse it as `Content-Type: Multipart/form-data`. but it also means that `fileUploadClient` silently overwrites the Content-Type header when uploadFile is called, that's kinda shitty behavior, it should at least generate a warning.. and finally it means you must modify the curl code to transfer the file in `multipart/form-data` format, so remove the `Content-Type: application/xml` header, and (too long for comment)

Comment: @PeterWesterlund and replace `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => file_get_contents ( $filepath )` with `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => array(new CURLFile($filepath))` - now curl will upload the xml in multipart/form-data format

Comment: @hanserik I got answer from the devs now: "Hi, Yeah the comment is correct. We don’t read raw text with content type application/xml. What you need to do is save it as an actual file *.xml. Then send us this with form-data and the filepath to your saved file.". That's what I tried to do in the first place....